# Attempt to calculate the shortest distance from origin to curve

Tags: calculus

I need help solving this problem.
A curve describes the equation $x^2 = 9 + xy$ on a Cartesian plane. What is  the shortest distance between $(0,0)$ and the curve?
I know I should use the distance formula, but when I replace the curve with $x^2$, it gives me the point $(0,0)$ which is not defined in the curve.

My procedure was: 
$d^2 = x^2 + y^2$ 
$f(x,y) =d^2 = 9 + xy + y^2$ 
So I optimized that equation. 
$f_x=y, f_y=x+2y$ 
$f_x=f_y=0$ 
Which gives the point $(0,0)$ as the closest, but it isn't in the domain.

Thx to the person who replied.

Comment: Please show your calculations, so one can find your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to parametrize the curve with some parameter $t$, such that $(x(t), y(t))$ obeys the equation.

The easiest way in this case is

$$\begin{aligned} 
  x(t) & = t \\ 
  y(t) & = \frac{t^2-9}{t} \\
\end{aligned}$$

and the distance (squared) function now is

$$ d^2 = x^2 + y^2 = \frac{2 t^4 - 18 t^2 + 81}{t^2} $$

which you find the minimum or maximum using $ \frac{\partial d^2}{\partial t} = 0$

$$ 0 = \frac{2 ( 2 t^4 - 3^4)}{t^3} $$

which is easily solved for $t$ and then for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: This answers the Problem statement, But OP didn't yet mentioned what exactly did he do to arrive at wrong calculations, I think That should be addressed first

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi - fair point, but the _op_ failed to show the steps they took and hence how they arrived at the wrong answer. I need to know the how in order to answer the why.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative solution**:
The shortest distance from the origin $O$ to a given curve is the same as the radius of the smallest circle
$$
x^2+y^2=r^2
$$
which is having the intersection point with a given curve
$$
c\ldots x^2=9+xy.
$$
Now, for $y$ we can have $y=\dfrac{x^2-9}{x}$, and take that in the equation of a circle. We will have:
$$
x^2+\frac{(x^2-9)^2}{x^2}=r^2 \iff \frac{x^4+x^4-18x^2+81}{x^2}=r^2 \iff 2x^4-x^2(18+r^2)+81=0.
$$
A circle will intersects a given curve when:
$$
(18+r^2)^2-4\cdot2\cdot81 \ge 0
$$
or
$$
(18+r^2)^2 \ge 648 \implies 18+r^2 \ge 18\sqrt{2} \implies r^2 \ge 18(\sqrt{2}-1) \implies \boxed{r \ge 3\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}}.
$$
Hence, the required shortest distance is $3\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}$.

**Figure**:
[image]